# Add interpolated field to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation

I have done a simple interpolation with the idw() function from the gstat package

```
B <- idw(x ~ 1,A,g,idp=2)
B <- data.frame(B)
head(B)

  lon    lat var1.pred var1.var
1 5.5 46.500  6.395490       NA
2 5.5 46.525  6.377175       NA
3 5.5 46.550  6.358851       NA
4 5.5 46.575  6.340517       NA
5 5.5 46.600  6.322175       NA
6 5.5 46.625  6.303826       NA
```

At first i tried to plot the field and then add the map, what succeeded but the view on the plotted country wasn't in the right angle. 
So now i want to plot the desired country and THEN add the field

```
library(ggplot2)
library(PBSmapping)
library(data.table)

xlim <- c(5.5,15.5)
ylim <- c(46.5,55.5)

ger <- map_data("worldHires")
setnames(ger,c("X","Y","PID","POS","region","subregion"))
ger <- clipPolys(ger,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,keepExtra=TRUE)

ggplot() + 
 coord_map(xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim) + 
 geom_polygon(data=ger,aes(X,Y,group=PID),fill="white",colour="black") +
 labs(x="lon",y="lat") + 
 theme_bw()
```

That code plots germany right as i want it to look like! But now i really have no idee how to add my interpolated field B.
I tried geom_tile(), but that doesn't work.

Is there usual way to make these kind of plots with ggplo2?

Comment: What if you add sth like `+ geom_path(data = B, aes(x= lon, y = lat), colour = "red")` or `+ geom_polygon(data = B, aes(x= lon, y = lat), colour = "red", fill = "blue")`?

Comment: Then it just adds a blue field that doesn't represent the measurments. Even when i use geom_polygon(data = B, aes(x= lon, y = lat,fill=var1.pred))